# Moved to server: an sqlparameter with parametername is not contained by this sqlparametercollection

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, listview, parameters

I moved a fully tested site to my web server and it keeps returning

> A SqlParameter with ParameterName 'Choices' is not contained by this
>   SqlParameterCollection.

Using VS 2010 I cannot replicate this error, everything works perfectly and passes all tests.

The server is running IIS 6 and net 3.5. I have used it in the past and have not had any problems. The site is built in asp.net 3.5 using vb.net.

Code:

```
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="Object" />
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Active" 
                         PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Boolean" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="Choices" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>

Protected Sub BoarListSQL_Selecting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles BoarListSQL.Selecting
    e.Command.Parameters("@UserId").Value = userId
    e.Command.Parameters("@Active").Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()
    e.Command.Parameters("@Choices").Value = lb_breeds.SelectedValue.ToString() 'breedChoice
End Sub

SelectCommand="If @Choices = 'ALL' BEGIN SELECT BoarID,Registration,Breed,Tag1,DOB,Name,BoarStudID,EntryDate,RemovalDate,Reason,Active,Location,BreedingHerdDate,Notes FROM [Table] WHERE ([UserID] = @UserID) AND ([Active] = @Active) END ELSE SELECT BoarID,Registration,Breed,Tag1,DOB,Name,BoarStudID,EntryDate,RemovalDate,Reason,Active,Location,BreedingHerdDate,Notes FROM [Table] WHERE ([UserID] = @UserID) AND ([Active] = @Active) AND ([Breed] = @Choices)"
```

I have Choices in the parameter list and I am adding a value when the select is ran.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about the problem, but you could simplify your query like so: SELECT BoarID, Registration, Breed, Tag1, DOB, Name, BoarStudID, EntryDate, RemovalDate,Reason,Active,Location,BreedingHerdDate,Notes FROM [Table] WHERE ([UserID] = @UserID) AND ([Active] = @Active) AND (@Choices = 'ALL' OR [Breed] = @Choices). Hey, you said "Any help is appreciated" :)

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't write it like that in the first place. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add addWithValue (should work fine) and be aware that sometimes you may need ' ' when you put some text into databases if you do not use it.

so one other solution could be :

```
e.Command.Parameters("@Choices").Value = "'" & lb_breeds.SelectedValue.ToString() & "'"  'breedChoice
```

You will find a good example on how to use it at :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.90).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: 'addWithValue' is not a member of 'System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection'

Comment: That's right it is in system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection whitch seems to be a child  of 'System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection'. Both are located in System.Data. For reference see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparametercollection(v=vs.90).aspx